# Is there a way to escape potential cell references using Google Sheets API?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I am working on a project that involves reading in several sheets from a Google Sheets doc. I have noticed that whenever I specify the sheet name to be something that could be a cell reference ("h7" for example) the read completes but loads zero values from the sheet. I've tried using "h-7" which works, but was wondering if there's a better solution out there.

Is this a known issue? If so, is there a way to escape this potential cell reference or am I completely wrong in assuming this is what's causing problems?

---

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()

result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range="H7").execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])
```

Comment: Kindly edit your code and include an example where you use "H7" as sheet name.

Comment: Forgot to specify, range tells google sheets where to look for the data. It is given in the form {sheet_name}!{cell_range} (e.g. H7!A1:B2 would be the A1, A2, B1 and B2 cells in the H7 sheet). If only the sheet name is specified all cells are read in. I've edited my code.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no alternative solution to this. When you use an A1 notation in the `range` parameter, It will automatically recognize it as address of a cell. You can either change the sheet name to a non A1 notation or add specific ranges.